# Trying to use user-defined function to populate new column in dataframe. What is going wrong?

Tags: r, dataframe, subset, replace

Super short version: I'm trying to use a user-defined function to populate a new column in a dataframe with the command:

```
TestDF$ELN<-EmployeeLocationNumber(TestDF$Location)
```

However, when I run the command, it seems to just apply EmployeeLocationNumber to the first row's value of Location rather than using each row's value to determine the new column's value for that row individually.

Please note: I'm trying to understand R, not just perform this particular task. I was actually able to get the output I was looking for using the Apply() function, but that's irrelevant. My understanding is that the above line should work on a row-by-row basis, but it isn't.

Here are the specifics for testing:

```
TestDF<-data.frame(Employee=c(1,1,1,1,2,2,3,3,3), 
                   Month=c(1,5,6,11,4,10,1,5,10), 
                   Location=c(1,5,6,7,10,3,4,2,8))
```

This testDF keeps track of where each of 3 employees was over the course of the year among several locations.

(You can think of "Location" as unique to each Employee...it is eseentially a unique ID for that row.)

The the function EmployeeLocationNumber takes a location and outputs a number indicating the order that employee visited that location. For example `EmployeeLocationNumber(8) = 2` because it was the second location visited by the employee who visited it.

```
EmployeeLocationNumber <- function(Site){
  CurrentEmployee <- subset(TestDF,Location==Site,select=Employee, drop = TRUE)[[1]]
  LocationDate<- subset(TestDF,Location==Site,select=Month, drop = TRUE)[[1]]
  LocationNumber <- length(subset(TestDF,Employee==CurrentEmployee & Month<=LocationDate,select=Month)[[1]])
  return(LocationNumber)
}
```

I realize I probably could have packed all of that into a single subset command, but I didn't know how referencing worked when you used subset commands inside other subset commands.

So, keeping in mind that I'm really trying to understand how to work in R, I have a few questions:

1. Why won't `TestDF$ELN<-EmployeeLocationNumber(TestDF$Location)` work row-by-row like other assignment statements do?
2. Is there an easier way to reference a particular value in a dataframe based on the value of another one? Perhaps one that does not return a dataframe/list that then must be flattened and extracted from?
3. I'm sure the function I'm using is laughably un-R-like...what should I have done to essentially emulate an INNER Join type query?

Comment: I don't quite get why `EmployeeLocationNumber(8) = 2`? Emplyee 3 was at locations 4,2 and 8 so I'd think the number was 3, not 2?

Comment: You are correct, it was a typo. It should have been EmployeeLocationNumber(3). Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Thanks to everyone for the information. I had not previously seen several of these functions [with, which, vectorize] so it was useful for them to be pointed out to me. Unfortunately, asking so many questions makes it hard to pick the right person to say "answered" my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The vectorized nature of R (aka row-by-row) works not by repeatedly calling the function with each next value of the arguments, but by passing the entire vector at once and operating on all of it at one time.  But in `EmployeeLocationNumber`, you only return a single value, so that value gets repeated for the entire data set.

Also, your example for `EmployeeLocationNumber` does not match your description.

```
> EmployeeLocationNumber(8)
[1] 3
```

Now, one way to vectorize a function in the manner you are thinking (repeated calls for each value) is to pass it through `Vectorize()`

```
TestDF$ELN<-Vectorize(EmployeeLocationNumber)(TestDF$Location)
```

which gives

```
> TestDF
  Employee Month Location ELN
1        1     1        1   1
2        1     5        5   2
3        1     6        6   3
4        1    11        7   4
5        2     4       10   1
6        2    10        3   2
7        3     1        4   1
8        3     5        2   2
9        3    10        8   3
```

As to your other questions, I would just write it as

```
TestDF$ELN<-ave(TestDF$Month, TestDF$Employee, FUN=rank)
```

The logic is take the months, looking at groups of the months by employee separately, and give me the rank order of the months (where they fall in order).

Comment: Thanks for answering my question about the row-by-row thing. I hadn't thought of it in that way because my main use of df$variable was in "subset" functions, where each separate element of the vector can be tested to determine if a row is included or not.

Answer (score 2):

A) `TestDF$Location` is a vector. Your function is not set up to return a vector, so giving it a vector will probably fail.

B) In what sense is Location:8 the "second location visited"?

C) If you want within group ordering then you need to pass you dataframe split up by employee to a funciton that calculates a result.

D) Conditional access of a data.frame typically involves logical indexing and or the use of which()

If you just want the sequence of visits by  employee try this:
(Changed first argument to Month since that is what determines the sequence of locations)

```
 with(TestDF, ave(Location, Employee, FUN=seq))
[1] 1 2 3 4 2 1 2 1 3
 TestDF$LocOrder <-  with(TestDF, ave(Month, Employee, FUN=seq))
```

If you wanted the second location for EE:3 it would be:

```
subset(TestDF, LocOrder==2 & Employee==3, select= Location)
#   Location
# 8        2
```

Comment: I think you want `FUN=rank`, not `FUN=order`

Comment: My results are returning what I thought @David R was asking for but now that I look at it again I think we are both wrong and the function should be `seq` to capture the sequence of visits.

Comment: If you pre-order by Month, then `seq` would work.  But if you don't pre-order, I'm pretty sure it is `rank`

Comment: I don't think so. There is no order or sequence information in the `Location` value. It could just as easily be a factor.

Comment: Oh, right.  It's the difference between using `ave(Location,...` and `ave(Month,...` where there is order information.

Answer (score 2):

Using logical indexing, the condensed one-liner replacement for your function is:

```
EmployeeLocationNumber <- function(Site){
    with(TestDF[do.call(order, TestDF), ], which(Location[Employee==Employee[which(Location==Site)]] == Site))
}
```

Of course this isn't the most readable way, but it demonstrates the principles of logical indexing and `which()` in R. Then, like others have said, just wrap it up with a vectorized *ply function to apply this across your dataset.

Comment: Thanks for illustrating logical indexing and the which() function.

Answer (score 0):

Your `EmployeeLocationNumber` function takes a vector in and returns a single value.
The assignment to create a new data.frame column therefore just gets a single value:

```
EmployeeLocationNumber(TestDF$Location) # returns 1

TestDF$ELN<-1 # Creates a new column with the single value 1 everywhere
```

1. Assignment doesn't do any magic like that. It takes a value and puts it somewhere. In this case the value `1`. If the value was a vector of the same length as the number of rows, it would work as you wanted.
2. I'll get back to you on that :)
3. Dito.

*Update*: I finally worked out some code to do it, but by then @DWin has a much better solution :(

```
TestDF$ELN <- unlist(lapply(split(TestDF, TestDF$Employee), function(x) rank(x$Month)))
```

...I guess the `ave` function does pretty much what the code above does. But for the record:

First I `split` the data.frame into sub-frames, one per employee. Then I `rank` the months (just in case your months are not in order). You could use `order` too, but `rank` can handle ties better. Finally I combine all the results into a vector and put it into the new column `ELN`.

*Update again* Regarding question 2, "What is the best way to reference a value in a dataframe?":

This depends a bit on the specific problem, but if you have a value, say `Employee=3` and want to find all rows in the data.frame that matches that, then simply:

```
TestDF$Employee == 3 # Returns logical vector with TRUE for all rows with Employee == 3
which(TestDF$Employee == 3) # Returns a vector of indices instead
TestDF[which(TestDF$Employee == 3), ] # Subsets the data.frame on Employee == 3
```

Comment: Thank you as well for the answers to my 3 numbered questions (see my comment to Brian below).

Comment: Any new insight into number 2? What is the best way to reference a value in a dataframe?

Comment: @DavidR some insights, see updated answer... Is that what you meant?

Comment: Actually, I'm just looking for a single value in that row. In general, I'm looking for the "right" way to say "Go find me the value of [attribute B] for the row in which the value of [attribute A] is [value Z]." In other words, I'm trying to find out the best way to think of a dataframe as delineating a function table of sorts. [This all assumes that the rows are distinct enough for the request to be well-defined, the answer is the same no matter which row you pick where the value of [Attribute A] equals [Value Z].

Comment: This method is painfully slow.