# Subsetting within user-defined function to assign values to target column

Tags: r, dataframe, subset, variable-assignment, user-defined-functions

I want to write a function that replaces the target column's values depending on the values of three other columns in the dataframe.

```
data <-data.frame("exists" = c(1,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,1), 
                  "specific" = c("yes", NA, "no", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "no"), 
                  "general" = c(NA, "yes", NA, "yes", "yes", NA, "no", NA, "no", NA), 
                  "therefore" = 0)
```

The target column is `therefore`, with a default value of 0.  I can manually assign values to `therefore` with three lines of subsetting (or nested `ifelse` statements, but I've seen suggestions to avoid `ifelse` for assigning values).

```
data[data["exists"] == 0, "therefore"] <- NA

data[grepl("yes", data[["specific"]], ignore.case=T), "therefore"] <- 1       

data[data["exists"] == 1 & grepl("yes", data[["general"]], ignore.case=T), 
"therefore"] <- 1
```

This gives the correct output:

```
> data["therefore"]
   therefore
1          1
2         NA
3          0
4         NA
5          1
6         NA
7         NA
8         NA
9          0
10         0
```

My attempt to write the code as a function so I can apply it to a variety of columns more readily:

```
fun <- function (doesitapply, string, speccol, gencol, target) {   

  data[data[doesitapply] == 0, target] <- NA

  data[grepl(string, data[[speccol]], ignore.case=T), target] <- 1

  data[data[doesitapply] == 1 & grepl(string, data[[gencol]], 
  ignore.case=T), target] <- 1    

}
```

When I use my new function `fun()`, no error is thrown but `therefore` appears unchanged from its default value.

```
fun(doesitapply = "exists", string = "yes", speccol = "specific", gencol = 
"general", target = "therefore")

> data["therefore"]
   therefore
1          0
2          0
3          0
4          0
5          0
6          0
7          0
8          0
9          0
10         0
```

Does this have something to do with subsetting using column names within a user-defined function? I have tried using `[[]]` instead of `[]` for all instances of subsetting in the function, but ...

```
 Error in `[[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, data[[doesitapply]] == 0, target,  : 
  only a single element should be replaced
```

I have had a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7800202/trying-to-use-user-defined-function-to-populate-new-column-in-dataframe-what-is) but I am finding it difficult to apply its answers to my case.  Guidance or suggestions are appreciated!

Comment: It's generally considered bad practice in R to write functions with (lasting) side effects. Try to rewrite the function to have `data` as one of the arguments, and have it return the data.frame in the state you want it. That way you don't have to worry about environments, scoping and all that stuff.

Comment: @AkselA Thank you for the feedback.  In future I'll avoid hard-coding arguments like `data` into my functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the code in your function is run outside of a function (after setting all the variables you used) it works as you expected:

```
doesitapply <- "exists"
string <- "yes"
speccol <- "specific"
gencol <- "general"
target <- "therefore"

data[data[doesitapply] == 0, target] <- NA
data[grepl(string, data[[speccol]], ignore.case=T), target] <- 1
data[data[doesitapply] == 1 & grepl(string, data[[gencol]], ignore.case=T), target] <- 1
```

This gives the same output as you provide from your original, not parameterised, code. However, this doesn't work in a function because it attempts to update a local version of `data`.

You can modify your function to change `<-` to `<<-` in all 3 lines. The `<-` operator always assigns in the local scope, whereas the `<<-` operator searches parent environments looking for an existing variable with that name.

Instead of assigning over 3 statements, it might be more typical to use `ifelse` which would be acceptable here, or perhaps the `case_when` function from `dplyr` https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/dplyr/versions/0.7.8/topics/case_when which avoids the need to use nesting.

It might also be possible to simplify the tests (e.g. avoid `grepl`) depending on the values you expect.

Comment: `<<-` instead of `<-` is the fix, thank you!  It also works with the nested 'ifelse' statements I mentioned in the second paragraph.